# Show alert message if we delete an application from ios simulator and device

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I want to show a alert message if we delete the application from ios simulator and device.I know that applicationWillTerminate is called if we kill an application.Do you know which delegate is call or there is any service in ios so that we can use this service to show a alert message.

Comment: Not possible to do this

Comment: Can't be done. Your app isn't running when deleted.

Comment: You can ask Tim Cook for more infomation! :D. Apple doesn't permit us do that

Comment: Actually there is a requirement in my company.

Comment: The requirement can't be met. There is no API that tells a deleted app that it has been deleted. How could there be? The app doesn't exist once it is deleted.